# How to refactor this Java snippet

Tags: java, refactoring, simplify

For some reason, I can't help but see redundancy in this chunk of code. Can anybody help me refactor it be more readable and concise?

```java
if (cachedParty == null || !cachedParty.equals(partyDto)) {
    if (cachedParty == null 
        && partyDto.getSellerStatusCode()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(SellerStatusEnum.ACTIVE.getCode())) 
    {
        pricingControlList.add(convertPartyDtoToPricingControl(partyDto));
    } else if (!cachedParty.equals(partyDto) 
        && cachedParty.getSellerStatusCode()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(SellerStatusEnum.ACTIVE.getCode()) 
        && !partyDto.getSellerStatusCode()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(SellerStatusEnum.ACTIVE.getCode())
    ) {
        pricingControlList.add(convertPartyDtoToPricingControl(partyDto));
    }
                                
    partyCache.put(partyDto.getSellerServicerNumber(), partyDto);
    partiesToSaveOrUpdate.add(partyDto);
}
```

Comment: You can use a lot of temporary intermediate variables to simplify - e.g. `final boolean isPartyDtoActive = ...`. Also, only the last two lines need to be in the initial condition block, the rest of it has independent checks.

Comment: Title is vague.  Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. The comparison to `SellerStatusEnum.ACTIVE` may be implemented as a function accepting a `Supplier<String>`
2. Top level comparison may be simplified to remove `cachedParty == null` - it is assumed from the code that `partyDto` is not null and therefore it is enough to check `!partyDto.equals(cachedParty)`

An example implementation:

```java
Function<Supplier<String>, Boolean> active = x -> SellerStatusEnum.ACTIVE.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(x.get());

if (!partyDto.equals(cachedParty)) {
    boolean partyActive = active.apply(partyDto::getSellerStatusCode);
    if (null == cachedParty && partyActive 
        || null != cachedParty && !partyActive && active.apply(cachedParty::getSellerStatusCode)
    ) {
        pricingControlList.add(convertPartyDtoToPricingControl(partyDto));
    }
    partyCache.put(partyDto.getSellerServicerNumber(), partyDto);
    partiesToSaveOrUpdate.add(partyDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making helper method `isActive(party)` which returns `partyDto.getSellerStatusCode().equalsIgnoreCase(SellerStatusEnum.ACTIVE.getCode()`. Additionaly, there is a possible NPE when `cachedParty == null` because `!cachedParty.equals(partyDto)` is calling `equals` for `null`. So, considering that `partyDto` is never `null`, this can be reduced to `!partyDto.equals(cachedParty)`.

Also, you're calling same method in `if(x) else if (y)` statement, so it can be reduced to one if statement with `x or y` check. So, let's rewrite your statement:

```
if (A or B) {
    if ((A and C) or (B and D and !C)) { F() }

    G()
}
```

As we decided in the first paragraph, `A or B = B`. So expression now looks like

```
if (B) {
    if ((A and C) or (B and D and !C)) { F() }

    G()
}

// and because inside first if statement B = true, we can remove B from nested if:

if (B) {
    if ((A and C) or (D and !C)) { F() }

    G()
}
```

So, by doing these optimisations we can get:

```
if (!partyDto.equals(cachedParty)) {

    if (cachedParty == null && isActive(partyDto) || (isActive(cachedParty) && !isActive(partyDto)) {
        pricingControlList.add(convertPartyDtoToPricingControl(partyDto));
    }

    partyCache.put(partyDto.getSellerServicerNumber(), partyDto);
    partiesToSaveOrUpdate.add(partyDto);
}
```

I've noticed that there is no `cachedParty != null` check in your nested if, so final result will be look like this:

```
if (!partyDto.equals(cachedParty)) {
    if (cachedParty == null && isActive(partyDto) || (cachedParty != null && isActive(cachedParty) && !isActive(partyDto)) {
        pricingControlList.add(convertPartyDtoToPricingControl(partyDto));
    }

    partyCache.put(partyDto.getSellerServicerNumber(), partyDto);
    partiesToSaveOrUpdate.add(partyDto);
}
```